# How to decode shortened Reed-Solomon code?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

I am working with a shortened version of $[n,k,d]$ Reed-Solomon code. I am encoding a message of size $k−l$ which gives a shortened code of size $n−l$ (this is equivalent to encoding the same message appended with $l$ $0s$). While decoding, I am following the Patterson algorithm, i.e. find $(n−k)$ syndromes, construct error-locator polynomial, etc. However, decoding is not working and I am guessing that the decoding algorithm needs to be modified. Can anybody write about how the decoding algorithm needs to be modified to decode the shortened version of the Reed-Solomon code?